# IP with /#number means?

Tags: ip

Can anybody explain IP with /# at the end means and what is it called?

Example: 55.11.65.20/2, 212.63.89.33/2

Thank you so much!

Comment: Off topic, it is the subnetmask.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Classless Inter-Domain Routing**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Answer (score 1):

The modern standard form of specification of the network prefix is CIDR notation, used for both IPv4 and IPv6. It counts the number of bits in the prefix and appends that number to the address after a slash (/) character separator:

```
192.168.0.0, netmask 255.255.255.0 is written as 192.168.0.0/24
In IPv6, 2001:db8::/32 designates the address 2001:db8:: and its network prefix consisting of the most significant 32 bits.
```

This notation was introduced with Classless Inter-Domain Routing (CIDR) in RFC 4632. In IPv6 this is the only acceptable form to denote network or routing prefixes.

Check this links for more

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing